# PL/SQL split one to many rows

Tags: regex, oracle, loops, plsql, split

I have a table like this.

> `|PARAMKEY  | PARAMVALUE
>   ----------+------------
>   KEY       |[["PAR_A",2,"SCH_A"],["PAR_B",4,"SCH_B"],["PAR_C",3,"SCH_C"]]`

I need to split the values into three columns and I use REGEXP_SUBSTR. Here is my code.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1,1 ) PARAMETER
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],[",]+', 1, 2) VERSION
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1, 3) SCHEMA
       FROM   tmp_param_table
where paramkey = 'KEY'
       UNION ALL 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1, 4 ) PARAMETER
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],[",]+', 1, 5) VERSION
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1, 6) SCHEMA
       FROM   tmp_param_table
where paramkey = 'KEY'
       UNION ALL 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1, 7 ) PARAMETER
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],[",]+', 1, 8) VERSION
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+', 1, 9) SCHEMA
       FROM   tmp_param_table
where paramkey = 'KEY';
```

and this is the result that i need.

> `PARAMETER | VERSION | SCHEMA
>   ---------+---------+-------
>   PAR_A    |2        |SCH_A
>   PAR_B    |4        |SCH_B
>   PAR_C    |3        |SCH_C`

But the value is too long and I hope there is another way to make it simplier by using loop or anything.
Thanks

Comment: See this ex. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings

Comment: How long is the PARAMVALUE column?

Comment: @DmitryGrekov the data_type is clob and i have to select the value into 52 row.

Comment: Is performance important in your problem? If it is, you may benefit from the string functions in the standard `dbms_lob` package. The execution time may drop by an order of magnitude or more compared to regular expression solutions. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#BABDDFDH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with tmp_param_table as
(
select 'KEY' as PARAMKEY  ,  '[["PAR_A",2,"SCH_A"],["PAR_B",4,"SCH_B"],["PAR_C",3,"SCH_C"]],["PAR_D",4,"SCH_D"]]' as PARAMVALUE from dual 
),
levels as        (select level as lv   from dual connect by level <= 156),
steps as (select lv-2  as step from levels  where MOD(lv,3)=0)
select step, (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+',1, step ) PARAMETER  FROM   tmp_param_table where paramkey = 'KEY')  parameter, 
             (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+',1, step+1 ) PARAMETER  FROM   tmp_param_table where paramkey = 'KEY') version,
             (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paramvalue, '[^],["]+',1, step+2 ) PARAMETER  FROM   tmp_param_table where paramkey = 'KEY') schema
               from  steps
```

**Here**

`levels` - returns numbers form `1` till `156` (`52*3`) (or whatever you need)

`steps` - are the numbers `1`, `4`, `7` etc with step `3`

**Results:**

```
1   PAR_A   2   SCH_A
4   PAR_B   4   SCH_B
7   PAR_C   3   SCH_C
10  PAR_D   4   SCH_D
13                    
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using regular expression

and part paramvalue column value into common separated value

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL, '[^],["]+', 1, 1) PARAMETER,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL, '[^],[",]+', 1, 2) VERSION,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(COL, '[^],["]+', 1, 3) SCHEMA
FROM
(
SELECT paramkey,REGEXP_SUBSTR(to_char(paramvalue),'[^][^]+',1,level ) COL
 from tmp_param_table
connect by regexp_substr(to_char(paramvalue),'[^][^]+',1, level) is not null
)
WHERE COL <>','
```

I hope this may help.

Comment: so close. I have to remove where clause because  I get error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 7

Comment: here I have missed some regular expression so got two extra rows for the comma.

Comment: change paramvalue to **to_char(paramvalue)**  at line 7 and 9 . see i have edited as per you need.

Comment: Yes. It works. We just need AND ROWNUM <=  in where clause. Thanx a lot.